# Elasticsearch Sink Connector Bulk request failed: Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

in my local laptop, my configuration work fine, but when i try elasticsearch cloud i got this error

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:611)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:333)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:234)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:244)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Bulk request failed: {"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]"}
    at io.aiven.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.handleMalformedDoc(BulkProcessor.java:426)
    at io.aiven.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.execute(BulkProcessor.java:380)
    at io.aiven.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.call(BulkProcessor.java:341)
    at io.aiven.connect.elasticsearch.bulk.BulkProcessor$BulkTask.call(BulkProcessor.java:327)
    ... 4 more
```

This is my specification

```
io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector (v5.0.3)
Elasticsearch (v8.7.1)
Kafka & kafka connect (v3.3.1)
```

im using elasticsearch cloud and aiven

This is my elasticsearch sink connector,

```
{
    "name": "ais-user.administrator.es-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
        "type.name": "_doc",
        "behavior.on.null.values": "DELETE",
        "topics": "ais-user.administrator",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "key.ignore": "false",
        "schema.ignore": "true",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "name": "ais-user.administrator.es-sink",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "connection.url": "",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
    },
    "tasks": [],
    "type": "sink"
}
```

this is example of kafka message
[Topic message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKtdD.png)

i already tried to delete all my topic message but i got same error & i already try to set type.name to null